# How read lock status in NodeJs?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I am running an external python code in NodeJs. The python code send command to the usb controller which interacts with a lock. The commands can be one of the following three:

- Open
- Close
- Status

I am able to succesfully send open/close command, but I am trying to see how to work out the status command. The status command simply state the status of the current lock such as open3, or close2, but i need to grab that information and figure out a way to display it to console once that command is issued.

**Below is how the open/close command are sent:**

```
 var comport = rows[i].comport;
          var command = "open" + rows[i].cubby_id;
          var commandClose = "close" + rows[i].cubby_id;


          console.log(command);
          console.log(comport);


          var options = {
            scriptPath: 'python/scripts',
            args: [command, comport, commandClose] // pass arguments to the script here

          };


          PythonShell.run('controlLock.py', options, function (err, results) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('results: %j', results);
          });
```

I tried sending the status command, but the results return is null.

Below, are the possible command that can be sent.
[image]

Below is the controlLock.py (without status)

```
import serial
import sys
import time

# 0 is the script itself, technically an argument to python
script = sys.argv[0]

# 1 is the command arg you passed
command = sys.argv[1]

# 2 is the comport arg you passed
comport = sys.argv[2]

commandClose = sys.argv[3]


ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 38400 #Suggested rate in Southco documentation, both locks and program MUST be at same rate 
ser.port = "COM{}".format(comport) 
ser.timeout = 5 
ser.open() 
#call the serial_connection() function 
ser.write(("%s\r\n"%command).encode('ascii'))
time.sleep(5)
ser.write(("%s\r\n"%commandClose).encode('ascii'))
```

**Update**

Below is the updated nodejs code

```
  var comport = rows[i].comport;
  var command = "open" + rows[i].cubby_id;
  var commandClose = "close" + rows[i].cubby_id;
            var commandStatus = "status" + rows[i].cubby_id;



  console.log(command);
  console.log(comport);


  var options = {
    scriptPath: 'python/scripts',
    args: [command, comport, commandClose, commandStatus] // pass arguments to the script here

  };


  PythonShell.run('controlLock.py', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('results: %j', results);
  });
```

Below is the updated python code

```
import serial
import sys
import time

# 0 is the script itself, technically an argument to python
script = sys.argv[0]

# 1 is the command arg you passed
command = sys.argv[1]

# 2 is the comport arg you passed
comport = sys.argv[2]

commandClose = sys.argv[3]
commandStatus = sys.argv[4]


ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 38400 #Suggested rate in Southco documentation, both locks and program MUST be at same rate 
ser.port = "COM{}".format(comport) 
ser.timeout = 5 
ser.open() 
#call the serial_connection() function 
ser.write(("%s\r\n"%command).encode('ascii'))
time.sleep(5)

ser.write(("%s\r\n"%commandClose).encode('ascii'))
time.sleep(2)
ser.write(("%s\r\n"%commandStatus).encode('ascii'))
```

It returns null for the status, when instead it should of return the string information

Comment: Why call out to a Python script when you can do serial communication from node with a third-party module like [`serialport`](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport)?

Comment: I had issue with serialport, and the original code was written in python. Hence, rather than rewritting everything i just ran the python code via a shell. It responds to the code for open/close works flawlesly (in terms of opening and closing the lock). The issue is when trying to get information from the status and then display it to console

Comment: I've included an update under my post